# 2 Variavel pelo header

Tags: php

Código:

```
$notapost = $_POST['nota'];
$cnpjpost = $_POST['cnpj'];

$objCheck = new Check();
$objCheck->setemail($notapost);
$objCheck->setlocal($cnpjpost);

$controller = new Comando($conn);
$controller->ListaDados($objCheck);


header ("location: ../view/FrontTab.php?nota=".$notapost);
```

Estou passando o `$notapost` pelo header como eu passo mais uma variável pelo header ? Que no caso seria o `$cnpjpost`.

Não sei como ficaria a sintaxe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro elemento de uma querystring deve ter o uma interrogação  `?` e os demais itens devem ter um e comercial `&`.

```
header ("location: ../view/FrontTab.php?nota=".$notapost."&cnpjpost=".$cnpjpost);
```

Ou ainda com `sprintf()`

```
header(sprintf("location: ../view/FrontTab.php?nota=%s&cnpjpost=%s", $notapost, $cnpjpost));
```

O php tem a função `http_build_query()` que a partir de um array gera a querystring.

```
$params= '?'.http_build_query(array('nota'=> $notapost, 'cnpj'=>cnpjpost));
header('location: ../view/FrontTab.php'. $params);
```